# How do I send data to wave.writeframesraw(data)

Tags: python, audio, buffer, typeerror, wave

I am trying to write a wave file using the native wave module in Python, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on what the 'data' field of wave.writeframesraw(data) means, or what a frame even is. I can not use any external modules or libraries because of installation issues on my computer. When I try and use the following example found on youtube I get an error.

```
data = [math.sin(x*2*math.pi*440/44100) for x in range(44100)]
#from tutorial:
BinStr = "" #create a binary string
for i in data:
    BinStr = BinStr + str(struct.pack('h', round(i*20000)))
file.writeframesraw(BinStr)


**file.writeframesraw(BinStr)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wave.py", line 414, in writeframesraw
    data = memoryview(data).cast('B')
TypeError: memoryview: str object does not have the buffer interface**
```

Comment: `BinStr = "" #create a binary string` this is concerning, is this from a tutorial that is using python2? Given that this is python 3 I'd imagine this should be `bytes` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was related to not setting all of the files parameters. When I use the wave.setparams((2, 2, 44100, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed')) it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to encode the str variable into unicode format, which is of the 'bytes' class.  In Python 2.xx, the writeframesraw function accepts str type data, but in python 3.xx, this no longer works, and writeframesraw now requires a 'bytes-like object'.

You can achieve this by simply converting your 'str' variable to unicode, which will be accepted by writeframesraw.

Try this out.

unicodeBinStr = BinStr.encode('utf-8')

file.writeframesraw(unicodeBinStr)

This will create a new variable called unicodeBinStr with the 'utf-8' encoded value of the data you have in the BinStr string.  Hope this works for you!